# What are the definitions of wait-related and timing columns in V$SQLAREA in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, query-optimization, database-administration

what are the definitions of the following columns:

- APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME
- CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME
- CLUSTER_WAIT_TIME
- USER_IO_WAIT_TIME
- PLSQL_EXEC_TIME
- JAVA_EXEC_TIME

in Oracle.

Also is the APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME the time the Query waits for the Application (e.g. a Mobile application) or is it something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full definition of this table and it's columns in the following link - 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2129.htm#REFRN30259

Application_wait_time records the amount of time spent  waiting for events in the Application wait class. This wait class  includes TX, TM, and other locks resulting from normal application DML,  and it’s a good bet that you can find your culprit SQLs by using this  column (cited from - https://oracle2amar.wordpress.com/category/oracle-scripts/)